# Filter DataFrame if every row value in some Column is not zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have panda dataframe look like this:

```
'a', 'b', 'c' ,'d', ...., 'z'
-----------------------------
1  , 2  , 3   , 4 , ...., 6
1  , 0  , 3   , 4 , ...., 6
0  , 0  , 0   , 4 , ...., 6
```

If i want to filter using single column, for example `a` can't be zero, i can do something like this

```
`df = df[df.a != 0]`
```

But how if i need to filter using multiple column, for example `a` and `b` can't be zero?

The result that i want something like this:

```
'a', 'b', 'c' ,'d', ...., 'z'
-----------------------------
1  , 2  , 3   , 4 , ...., 6
1  , 0  , 3   , 4 , ...., 6
```

Comment: Try `df = df[df.a != 0 and df.b !=0]

Comment: What if i have a lot of column, let say i save the columns that i need to filter in a list? @Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare filtered columns with `0` with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (same as `!=`) for new boolean DataFrame and then check if at least one `True`s per row with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df[['a','b']])
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  0
2  0  0

print (df[['a','b']].ne(0))
       a      b
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False  False

print (df[['a','b']].ne(0).any(1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

df = df[df[['a','b']].ne(0).any(1)]
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  z
0  1  2  3  4  6
1  1  0  3  4  6
```

Comment: i tried that but, my dataframes return 0 row now, it look like that code eliminate every row if value in 'a' or 'b' is zero, what am i looking for is if 'a' and 'b' is zero, the second code is quite problematic if i have a lot of column as filtering parameter, how?

Comment: I update my question to give better explanation, thanks :)